# How can I extract values of an attribute and chain it to multiple other values via XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have an awful bit of HTML I need to extract info from but I can't figure out the syntax to do what I need.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="divRow mainpage-transfer-neutral">
    <div class="divCell Name" style="text-align:left;">
        <span class="flag"><a href="/path/country" title="Country"><img alt="Country" src="/img/country.png"/></a></span>
        <a href="/userdb/user1" title="user1">user1</a><br />
        <span class="flag"><a href="/path/country" title="Country"><img alt="Country" src="/img/country.png"/></a></span>
        <a href="/userdb/user2" class="new" title="user2">user2</a><br />
        <span class="flag"><a href="/path/country" title="Country"><img alt="Country" src="/img/country.png"/></a></span>
        <a href="/userdb/user3" class="new" title="user3">user3</a><br />
        <span class="flag"><a href="/path/country" title="Country"><img alt="Country" src="/img/country.png"/></a></span>
        <a href="/userdb/user4" title="user4">user4</a><br />
        <span class="flag"><a href="/path/country" title="Country"><img alt="Country" src="/img/country.png"/></a></span>
        <a href="/userdb/user5" title="user5">user5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divCell">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="divCell Date">01-01-2000</div>
    <div class="divCell Date">01-01-2020</div>
</div>
```

For my sample, here's what I'd like the output to be:

```
country
user1
Lorem Ipsum
01-01-2000
01-01-2020

country
user2
Lorem Ipsum
01-01-2000
01-01-2020

country
user3
Lorem Ipsum
01-01-2000
01-01-2020

...
```

I know how to get country and user but I can't figure out how to fetch the info outside of the `divCell Name` and chain it to each users.

This is what I've got so far:

```
//*[@class='divRow mainpage-transfer-neutral']/div[1]//@title
```

And this is what it outputs:

```
country
user1
country
user2
country
user3
country
user4
country
user5
```

PS: Very sorry if the title is confusing I couldn't figure out a way to phrase this problem lol

Comment: Extracting values is a good job for XPath, but chaining values together is usually done in the hosting language such as XSLT, Python, JavaScript, Java, etc.

Comment: What version of XPath?  Also, your desired output contains the literal `country` but this is found nowhere in your input example.  Is that a constant literal or is that the `Country` found in your title attributes?